# Downloader access problem

Tags: magento-1.9, downloader

I can't login to downloader with the error: Unable to write to the configuration file.

file permission of downloader/config.ini is 666,
any idea?

[image: Unable to write to the configuration file.]

Comment: 666 is a weird setting, try 644 instead. Basically, all files should have 644 and folders should have 755.

Comment: no way, files 644 and folder 755, same behavior

Comment: check file ownership then. Most of the times, this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check with your hosting provider on whether they are running SuPHP or SuExec as the file permissions will be different.

If the server is using SuPHP or SuExec, all files should be set to 644 and all directories should be set to **755** (instead of 666 and 777 which are not secure).

You may also need to make sure that the files ownership are all correct and unless you have SSH access, this will need to be checked with your hosting provider as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm using php5, user ubuntu, group www-data. I set all folder permissions 755 and file 644

Comment: Solved, I have to set user and group to www-data.

Comment: Yes, it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions not fixing this problem for you?

The system seems to require that the ownership of the files belongs to the user that runs the webserver. Having group write, or world write (which would imply that any user could write) does not seem to be enough. So for example my server is running Debian, with the Bitnami LAMP stack and their Magento module. The owner of the root magento folder is user "bitnami". The webserver runs as user "daemon". Although daemon group had write access I could not get downloaded to work until daemon was the owner:

`sudo chown -R daemon downloader`

You may also need to change ownership of another file:

`sudo chown daemon var/brute-force.ini`